# Print console log results to multiple instances of a div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops, console

This is a part 2 to a question I had about a month ago. At that time, I needed a script to loop through all products on an eCommerce web page and calculate the percentage savings to the console log.

While this has been achieved, there seems to be an issue when I try to assign the values to a div in HTML.

The algorithm I'm using for the percentage discount calculation looks like this:

```
//Calculate savings per item
function getPrice(elem){
  return elem.match(/\d+.\d{0}/);
}

function getDiscount(regPrice, salePrice){
  let disc = (regPrice - salePrice) * 100 / regPrice;
  return disc < 0 ? 0 : disc;
}

let $regPrice = $('.regular-price');
let $salePrice = $('.sale-price');

$regPrice.each(function(k, v){
  let regPrice = getPrice($regPrice[k].innerHTML);
  let salePrice = getPrice($salePrice[k].innerHTML);
  let discount = getDiscount(regPrice, salePrice);

  console.log("You Save: " + discount.toFixed(0) + "%");
});
```

This is for the most part doing exactly what I wanted it to do, but getting these values from console log to an html div class seems to just want to grab the first value and use it across the board.

For example, when I hook in a console override or any type of output to HTML, the DOM grabs the first value in the array of console log items and re-uses that same value for each item on the page:

```
if (typeof console  != "undefined") 
if (typeof console.log != 'undefined')
    console.olog = console.log;
else
    console.olog = function() {};

console.log = function(message) {
console.olog(message);
$('.youSave').append("You Save: " + discount.toFixed(0) + "%");
};
console.error = console.debug = console.info =  console.log
```

While the console shows the following:
[image]

The DOM is only getting the first value, then repeating that across all items on the page.

**I would like for each div class to show the exact percentage savings while silently discarding "NaN" or 0% results**. Essentially any value greater than 1 should be displayed.

The HTML output on the page with the products is structured like so:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 product-grid-item">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body text-center shadow" style="height: 341.2px;">
        <a href="/link1.aspx" class="grid-product-link">
          <div class="grid-item-image-wrap">
                <img src="ae00-3487.jpg" alt="alt-text-here" class="grid-item-image product-image center-block">
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item-name-wrap">Product 1 (over 1k)</div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer text-center">
        <div class="grid-item-price-wrap">
            <a href="link1.aspx" class="price-button">
                <div class="price-wrap">
                    <div class="price regular-price">
                        <span>Retail Price:</span> 
                        $2,249.00
                    </div>
                    <div class="price sale-price alert alert-green shadow">
                        <span>Our Price:</span>
                        $1,759.00
                    </div>
                    <div class="youSave text-uppercase text-success"></div> 
                    <meta itemprop="price" content="1759.0000">
                    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item-promotions-wrap"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 product-grid-item">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body text-center shadow" style="height: 341.2px;">
          <a href="link2.aspx" class="grid-product-link">
              <div class="grid-item-image-wrap">
                  <img src="ae00-1856.jpg" alt="alt-text-here" class="grid-item-image product-image center-block">
              </div>
              <div class="grid-item-name-wrap">Product 2 (under 1k)</div>
          </a>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer text-center">
        <div class="grid-item-price-wrap">
            <a href="link2.aspx" class="price-button">
                <div class="price-wrap">
                    <div class="price regular-price">
                        <span>Retail Price:</span> 
                        $559.00
                    </div>
                    <div class="price sale-price alert alert-green shadow">
                        <span>Our Price:</span> 
                        $439.00
                    </div>
                    <div class="youSave text-uppercase text-success">You Save: 21%</div> 
                    <meta itemprop="price" content="439.0000">
                    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-item-promotions-wrap"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

And follows this schema throughout all products on a page. I have placed the self closing div class of "youSave" in the page and that's where I would like to show the results coming from console log.

Working Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/sLb16nhg/2/

Comment: Can you post an exact working example ?

Comment: Added fiddle above.

Comment: You just need to discard the 0%?

Comment: I need it to appear in the "youSave" div and discard 0% or sometimes "NaN". Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have tweaked your code a bit. It would be better if you iterate the parent div `.price-wrap`.

```js
//Calculate savings per item
function getPrice(elem){
  return elem.match(/\d+.\d{0}/);
}

function getDiscount(regPrice, salePrice){
  let disc = (regPrice - salePrice) * 100 / regPrice;
  return disc < 0 ? 0 : disc;
}

let $priceWrap = $('.price-wrap');
$priceWrap.each(function(k, v){
  let $regPrice = $priceWrap[k].children[0];
  let $salePrice = $priceWrap[k].children[1];
  let $discountPrice = $priceWrap[k].children[2];

  let regPrice = getPrice($regPrice.innerHTML);
  let salePrice = getPrice($salePrice.innerHTML);
  let discount = getDiscount(regPrice, salePrice);

  if ( !isNaN(discount) && discount !== 0 ){
    $discountPrice.innerHTML = discount.toFixed(0) + "%";
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-wrap">
    <div class="price regular-price">
      <span>Retail Price:</span>
      $549.00
    </div>
    <div class="price sale-price">
      <span>Our Price:</span>
      $489.00
    </div>
   <div class="youSave"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="price-wrap">
    <div class="price regular-price">
       <span>Retail Price:</span>
       $2599.00
    </div>
    <div class="price sale-price">
      <span>Our Price:</span>
      $2255.00
    </div>
   <div class="youSave"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="price-wrap">
    <div class="price regular-price">
       <span>Retail Price:</span>
       $299.00
    </div>
    <div class="price sale-price">
      <span>Our Price:</span>
      $155.00
    </div>
   <div class="youSave"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="price-wrap">
    <div class="price regular-price">
       <span>Retail Price:</span>
       $699.00
    </div>
    <div class="price sale-price">
      <span>Our Price:</span>
      $555.00
    </div>
   <div class="youSave"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="price-wrap">
    <div class="price regular-price">
       <span>Retail Price:</span>
       $0.00
    </div>
    <div class="price sale-price">
      <span>Our Price:</span>
      $155.00
    </div>
   <div class="youSave"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @BlackPearl

Comment: One comment here @BlackPearl, any price over $1000 seems to not be calculating. All prices under 1k are working as expected. Any thoughts?

Comment: Like? Example input?

Comment: updated the HTML snippet in original question. Thanks.

Comment: Any number larger than 999.99 gets ignored by the math from the looks of things.Looks like it's being caused by the comma number separator at 1k. Removing the comma will make it work.

Comment: Seriously, remove the comma and run again. It will work.

Comment: Of course, comma won't work. I've changed the `getPrice` function in the fiddle to replace the comma. You can check it, but I would suggest you to look for better ways to parse the int.

Comment: link to fiddle?

Comment: Just change the method `getPrice` method to `return elem.replace(/,/g,'').match(/\d+.\d{0}/);`